# Flex:how to disable particular item in combobox?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I have ComboBox With ArrayCollection as DataProvider. Data will come from Databse as ArrayCollection. I'm Adding Item to ArrayCollection "-Select Item-" at 0th index and setting selected index=0 for combobox.

[image]

My question is How to disable that(-select Course-) item?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use `prompt` property [of `DropDownList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html#prompt) or [`ComboBox`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html#prompt) for that and combine it with `selectedIndex = -1` as initial value.

Comment: Ya, Im not getting property prompt for combobox in flex4. I can use `cmbCourse.TextInput.Text="-select-"`. But is it possible to disable an item in a  combobox that will help me lot.

Comment: This way you break incapsulation. Why not to use `prompt`?

Comment: I am not getting property prompt for combobox. I am using flex4.

Comment: I recommend you to use DropDownList as far as user hasn't possibility to enter custom text in your case. Or switch to Flex 4.5.

Comment: @M.S.Nayak or else u can use the mx:Combobox to use the prompt since flex 4 supports the flex 3 components also

Comment: @Sudharsanan Yes. Why i used s:Combobox  is user can type(if he wants)and filter items right?

Answer (score 1):

Worst case an item renderer to show things as disabled. Then simply ignore the click if it has the property disabled. (this implies your list is overloaded with a property like isDisabled.

Mylist.selctedItem.isDisabled